# How to get sum two fields separately in two tables with same sql statments

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, sum

I have created 3 tables

1. Partners Table contains (Partner_ID, Partner_Name).
2. Expenses Table contains (ID, Partner_ID, Ex_Date, Ex_Amount).
3. Payments Table contains (ID, Partner_ID, Pay_Date, Pay_Amount).

I tried to create SQL statement to give me the sum of expenses and the sum of payments for each partner but I couldn't, it gives me a big result greater than the true result for each partner always

I have used LEFT JOIN WITH SUM(CASE WHEN ....)
I tried many support links here but I didn't succeed to apply it on my case!

Thanks advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use joins, or correlated subqueries:

```
select
    p.*,
    (
        select sum(e.ex_amount) 
        from expenses e 
        where e.partner_id = p.partner_id
    ) as total_expenses,
    (
        select sum(a.pay_amount) 
        from payments a 
        where a.partner_id = p.partner_id
    ) as total_payments
from partners p
```